# All Possible Causes of 403 Forbidden From CSRF

Tags: django

I want to know all the possible triggers of a 403 Forbidden from CSRF. What causes this error to show up and how can I prevent it, in all of its cases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities though.

**You didn't use one in form**

Obvious. Include `{% csrf_token %}` immediately after your form tag, before all the form fields.

**Request needs csrf_token**

In some cases involving POST requests, Django will force the use of a csrf_token. There are ways to get around this using custom middleware, but it's too complicated and is prone to cross-site forgery attacks. Instead, just ensure a csrf_token is passed to your view:

```py
@csrf_protect
def your_view(request):
    pass


@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
class your_view(View):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!! For the second point, are those decorators required? Or is it default? Thanks!

Comment: Since I'm using React as the frontend as opposed to HTML, sometimes the request can't be completed as Django wants the token but didn't throw one on default (I can't always use UpdateView since I require more flexibility, so I need to include a token of my own).

Comment: Basically you will need it in a case where you want to do specific actions (that require a token) but Django's corresponding defaults are either inflexible or won't come with csrf.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. How can I simulate a CSRF error? I have a form and it sometimes throws the error. How can I simulate to test it? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't answer this question as I had done very few tests. All I do is to test the form in every possible way until I can't find any errors.